# Building a hex string from ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, interface, hex

I have already calculated the remainders, but my problem is the actual conversion from the remainders to the new hexadecimal characters. All I need to do in the Dec2Hex class is get the remainder arraylist from the superclass (which I have done) and then convert it into a string by using the character array hexDigits[]. I have to step though the remainder arraylist in a loop and build the hex string, but I am not sure how to go about this.

```
//this is the Binary to Decimal implementation which hex2dec is based off of

package business;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Bin2Dec implements Conversion{
    public static final String VALUEDESC ="Binary";
    public static final String RESULTDESC ="Decimal";
    private String origval, result;
    private ArrayList<String> resultsteps;
    private String emsg;
    private boolean valid;

    public Bin2Dec(String value) {
        emsg = "";
        origval = value;
        if (valid =isValid(value)) {  //valid will be true or false
            convert(value);
        } else {
            emsg = "Illegal, binary value (must be only zeros and ones";
        }
    }
    private boolean isValid(String v) {
        for (int i=0; i< v.length(); i++) {
            if (v.charAt(i) != '1' && v.charAt(i) != '0') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // we can do isValid because we declared private boolean valid
    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.valid;
    }
    private void convert(String v) {
        long r = 0;
        String reverse = new StringBuilder(v).reverse().toString();
        resultsteps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
            if (reverse.charAt(i) == '1') {
                long p = (long) Math.pow(2,i);
                r += p;
                resultsteps.add("There is a(n) " + p + " in the number (2^" + i + ")" );
            }
        }
        this.result = String.valueOf(r);
    }
    @Override
    public String getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getProcessLog() {
        return this.resultsteps;
    }
    @Override
    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return this.emsg;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.origval;
    }

}
```

**Implementation**

```
//this is the hex2dec implementation I created 

package business;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Dec2Hex extends Dec2Num {
    public static final String VALUEDESC="Decimal";
    public static final String RESULTDESC="Hexadecimal";
//    private ArrayList<String> codes;
    public static final int BASE=16;
    private String binaryresult;
    char[] hexDigits = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
              'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    String hex = "";

    public Dec2Hex(String value) {
        super(value, Dec2Hex.BASE);
        this.binaryresult="";  

    }


    @Override
    public String getResult() {
        if(!super.isValid()) {return "Invalid Value";}
        for(Integer i : super.getRemainders()) {                             //we deleted remainders in Dec2Bin so we call super
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(i);
            this.binaryresult += String.valueOf(i);
        }
        switch (hex) {


        }

       return this.binaryresult;
    }

//    public ArrayList<String> getHexConversion(int d) {
//        char[] hexDigits = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
//              'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
//        String hex = "";
//        while (d > 0) {
//            int digit = d % BASE;              
//            hex = hexDigits.charAt(digit) + hex; 
//            d = d / BASE;
//        }
//    return codes;
//    }

    //    public ArrayList<String> getHexConversion(int d) {
//
//        String hex = "";
//        while (d > 0) {
//            int digit = d % BASE;             
//            char hexDigits = (hex <= 9 && hex >= 0);
//            (char)(hexDigits + '0') : (char)(hexDigits- 10 + 'A');
//        }
//    return this.binaryresult;
//    }
}
```

**Interface and abstract implementation**

```
//interface

public interface Conversion {
    public String getValue();
    public String getResult();
    public boolean isValid();
    public ArrayList<String> getProcessLog();
    public String getErrorMsg();
    //each subclass should fulfill these methods   
}

//abstract implementation

public abstract class Dec2Num implements Conversion{
    private String origval, emsg;
    private boolean valid;
    private int base;
    private ArrayList<String> resultsteps;
    private ArrayList<Integer> remainders;

    public Dec2Num(String value, int base) {  //int base b/c it needs to know what to divide down by
       emsg ="";
       origval = value;
       this.base = base;
       try {
           long n = Long.parseLong(value);
           if (n < 0 ) {
               emsg = "Bad decimal value: must be positive.";
               this.valid = false;
           } else {
              this.valid = true;
              resultsteps = new ArrayList<>();
              remainders = new ArrayList<>();
              convertByRecur(n);
           }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           emsg = "Illegal value: not a decimal integer";
           this.valid = false;
        }
    }//end of constructor
        @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.valid;
    }
    private void convertByRecur(long n) {
        int r = 0;

        r = (int)(n % this.base);
        long newval = n / this.base;
        resultsteps.add(n + " divided by " + this.base + "="
                        + newval + " w/remainder of: "  +r);

        if (newval > 0) {
            convertByRecur(newval);  //recursive call
        } 
        remainders.add(r);
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getProcessLog() {
        return this.resultsteps;
    }
    @Override
    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return this.emsg;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.origval;
    }
    @Override
    public abstract String getResult();

    protected ArrayList<Integer> getRemainders() {
        return this.remainders;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of dumping a lot of code, put up a **real** [mcve] and give concrete example input / output where your code fails.

Comment: It’s an afwul lot of code alright, and I’m afraid it may have deterred some that would have wanted to help a lot earlier. What we needed were really just the 6 troublesome lines of code from `getResult()` and a declaration of an `ArrayList<Integer>` (that would substitute for your super call, which also is irrelevant to the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calling `Integer.toHexString()` should work, but it bypasses the idea of your `hexDigits` array. Only potential issue is it will give you lowercase letters `a` though `f` where you may want the uppercase equivalents.

`String.valueOf(i)` is incorrect. It will give you `7` if `i` is 7, but `11` if `i` 11, where you want `B`, the hex digit. You could do just

```
        this.binaryresult += hex;
```

You don’t need your `switch` statement at all.

Supposing you do want to use your `hexDigits` array:

- To get the correct `char` out of the array, just use `hexDigits[i]`.
- You can append the `char` directly to a `String` without converting it to a `String` first:

  ```
      this.binaryresult += yourChar;
  ```

I will let you struggle with it a bit before offering my version of the code. I believe you can do it.

Comment: I'm not used to posting on stack overflow, so thankz for the feedback! You helped me out a lot b/c Java is confusing to me sometimes; Actually, it's my first experience in programming since Java 1.